# PHP multidimensional array search with provided array column (using PHP5 array_column)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need help with array search. The array example is:

```
$users=Array
(
    0 => Array
    (
        'id' => 111,
        'name' => 'Sandra Shush',
        'sources' => '1234,678,780'
    ),

    1 => Array
    (
        'id' => 112,
        'name' => 'Stefanie Mcmohn',
        'sources' => '32,99,85'
    ),

    2 => Array
    (
        'id' => 113,,
        'name' => 'Michael',
        'sources' => '896,1213,1918'
    ),

    3 => Array
    (
        'id' => 113,,
        'name' => 'Michael',
        'sources' => '72'
    )
);
```

I need to extract the key from the provided array above, where the "sources" key matches the search string (integer).

I've tried with:

```
$key = array_search('99', array_column( $users, 'sources') ); // false
```

But of course, there's no chance to retrieve the key with this method. It only works if source key has only one value, for example:

```
$key = array_search('72', array_column( $users, 'sources') ); // 3
```

Is there a way to achieve this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `foreach` loop along with `preg_match` like as

```
$result = [];

foreach($users as $key => $value){
    if(preg_match("/\b99\b/",$value['sources']) !== false){
        $result[] = $key;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/bO6g7)

Comment: with strpos it will also find `99` in values like `12,199,46`

Comment: Yes you're right that got out of my mind hold I'll update my answer

Comment: I think he wanted to use built-in functions to avoid writing loops. Since that's not possible I think it's best to copy these columns to another array, split the values in the CSV, then perform the search using his method. I'm just too lazy to write that down :P

Comment: Basically for now, this is the only solution, even though the array that I have in production is large. Thank you both . I will investigate the option to split the array and to write those values somewhere else prior to performing a search.